# Passing enum as template paramer

Tags: c++, templates

Why the following template function

```
template<typename T>
bool isEqual(const T &v0, const T &v1)
{
    return v0 == v1;
}
```

does not compile when v1 and v2 are enumerated?
How can should I write a template function which compares variable with enum: `isEqual(color, RED)`?

```
template<typename T>
bool isEqual(const T &v0, const T &v1)
{
    return v0 == v1;
}


int main()
{
    enum Enum
    {
        E1,
        E2,
        E3
    } v1, v2;

    v1 = E1;
    v2 = E1;

    isEqual(v1, v2);

}
```

***TestProject/main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
TestProject/main.cpp:31: error: no matching function for call to 'isEqual(main()::Enum&, main()::Enum&)'***

Comment: Yes it does compile... can you post an example where it doesn't compile?

Comment: Also, the usefulness of such a function is questionable.

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae, Before C++11 I imagine, where Clang's error is extremely clear: *error: template argument uses __local type__ 'Enum'*

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae, [Not for me.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/330baaa28a2f4120)

Comment: MSVC supported breaking this limitation as an extension prior to C++11 and I believe the other compilers too. It only existed because of `export` and since nobody implemented it...

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae, What's wrong with that? `-pedantic` only affects non-standard code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably means that your compiler is out of date.

Before C++11, types without linkage (e.g. types declared within a function) couldn't be used as template arguments. This rather odd restriction has now been removed.

Your example should compile if you either move the `enum` declaration to namespace scope (giving it external linkage), or use a modern compiler: http://ideone.com/QZQjHI

Comment: I'm on gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4). Probably "RedHattiness" is what makes it out of date...